# Use jade mixin inside code block

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Is there a way to use [jade mixin](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/) inside [javascript code block](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/)?

I have next use case:

```
mixin YYYYMMDD(date)
  = date.getFullYear() + '-'
  = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-'
  = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
```

So I need to use this mixin inside

```
input(
   value=YYYYMMDD(date)
)
```

**Update:**
I had to remake those mixins to js functions, so it looks similar to next:

```
- function YYYYMMDD(date)
    - var flDate = date.getFullYear() + '-';
    - flDate += ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-';
    - flDate += ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    - return flDate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is, that you write this code on your server, then you can also use some other syntax, for instance coffeescript or even better in this case, some libraries like moment

When you render your template, you just add a helper object to your locals:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var YYYYMMDD = function(date) {
  return moment(date).format('YYYYMMDD');
}

// express code

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  var locals = getLocalsForTest();
  locals.helpers = {
    YYYYMMDD: YYYYMMDD
  };
  res.render('template.jade', {locals: locals});
});
```

and in your template you can just call this

```
input(value=helpers.YYYYMMDD(date))
```